# How to train model when Data is consist of matrices

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, svm, scikit-learn

I am new to ML and python. I am facing an issue related to the training SVM model. I have a training data file size (200,50,120). Where 200 are my examples (or experiments). While Actual data is a matrix X= 50x120. Here 120 are features and 50 is the sample size. On the other side, there is a Y=labels file with size (200,1). I am confused, how to train the model with a matrix? I read some comments about flattering the features into an array. whats is its purpose?

Comment: so what are the 50 "samples"? Time series?

Comment: What does "flattering the features" mean? Flattening perhaps? But then...flatten to put the features into an array? What for? What about using matrix algebra for matrices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your case, the input to an SVM model (assuming you are using scikit-learn) is a 2D array with a shape of (n_samples, n_features). Now given the dimensions of your data, think about how it can be brought to this form so that the `fit` method from `sklearn.svm.SVC` can be used directly. The quickest idea that comes to the mind is to somehow change the dimension of the matrix (`50x120`) because we already have `200` as the number of samples. The way it is done in machine learning is the data is "flattened" such that it can be represented by a vector. Another interesting way to think about this is when you vectorize your data, you are essentially representing it by a point in that dimensional space (that is, in `50x120`-dimensional space, each example becomes a point). So, with the help of "flattening", the input to the model is nothing but 200 data points, each in `50x120`-dimensional space.

Here are some quick references for training an SVM model:

1) [Scikit-SVM](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html)

2) [SVM code examples](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/index.html#support-vector-machines)

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of flattening (or reshaping in general) is to match dimensions of data and model layer to enable training.